# should i able to load entire html page using htmlUnitDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

I am using Chrome driver for my Selenium test case. It is working fine. There is a performance issue in my project, so I want to migrate the testcase from `ChromeDriver` to `HtmlUnitDriver`. When I am trying to use `HtmlUnitDriver` in my testcase, by just changing the driver name with `HtmlUnitDriver`, the selenium testcase is not working.

After working around with this driver, I thought that `HtmlUnitDriver` is not loading the entire page.

Why I am telling this is because `HtmlUnitDriver` can find some `div` id's which are in the beginning of the page.

Other `div`s were not found by this driver. I am getting `NoSuchElementException` for this div id's.

So please help me to resolve this problem in my project.

Comment: you'll need to add a sample html page or link to site plus the id's you are trying to find for anyone to be able to help

Answer (score 2):

Aren't the elements you are looking for created by JavaScript/AJAX calls? [You might need to enable JavaScript support in HtmlUnitDriver first.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)

But beware, it could work well, but it could behave differently from what you see in the real browsers.

Otherwise, are you using [Implicit/Explicit Waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for your searches? Even with JS enabled, sometimes it takes a while before all asynchronous requests are handled.